# Мультиязычный сайт на WP на Polylang+ACF

Tags: html, wordpress, acf, polylang

Делаю мультиязычный сайт на wordpress (блоки через ACF). На главной русской странице все правильно отображается. Установил плагин polylang, разделил главную страницу и посты на языки, но эти страницы не видят блоки постов, там пусто. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, уже всю голову сломал, заранее спасибо. [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Страницы]

Comment: https://polylang.pro/doc/working-with-acf-pro/ : The compatibility with ACF Pro is provided by Polylang Pro

Comment: Платной версией нет возможности пользоваться, по другому никак? Перевод не нужен, нужно просто, чтобы можно было также редактировать, как на русской странице.

Comment: как вариант можно использовать вместо acf - cmb2

Answer (score 0):

Решил путем снятия галочек в настройках polylang в разделе Synchronization -> Custom fields